# How to assign a String variable to a dataset?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I read rows from a file, do a check on the first row and then I have to write the next rows of the file into a table called "TestTable" with a method that works on DataSet. It tells me that I can't insert the string type in DataSet.

```
Dim myStream As Stream = Nothing
    Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()

    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "Z:\FitalogItalia\KMaster\SPEKM"   'ATTENZIONE CAMBIARE IN "C:\"
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True


    If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Try
            myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()
            If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                Dim objReader As New StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName)
                Dim ControlLine As String = ""
                Dim sLine As String = ""
                Dim arrText As New ArrayList()
                ControlLine = objReader.ReadLine
                If (ControlLine.Contains("H06") And ControlLine.Contains("SPEKM")) Then
                    sLine = objReader.ReadLine
                    Dim indice As Integer = 0
                    Do

                        If Not sLine Is Nothing Then
                            arrText.Add(sLine)
                            DB_SQL.SetDBfromDataset("INSERT INTO TestTable (riga) VALUES (" + arrText.Item(indice) + ");", "TestTable")
                            indice = +1
                        End If

                    Loop Until objReader.ReadLine.Count - 1
                End If
                objReader.Close()


            End If
        Catch Ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message)
        Finally
            ' Check this again, since we need to make sure we didn't throw an exception on open.
            If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                myStream.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    End If
```

**UPDATE** I ADDED THE FUNCTION WITH WHICH I LOAD THE DATA ON THE DB. THE PROBLEM IS THE ARRAY LIST BECAUSE I NEED TO PASS A DATASET

```
Public Function SetDBfromDataset(ByVal ds As Data.DataSet, ByVal TN As String) As Integer
DBadapter.InsertCommand = New SqlCommand
        TmpSQLstring = "INSERT INTO " & TN

        ' ottengo la lista dei campi
        ListFields = " ("


        For Each myCol In ds.Tables(0).Columns

            If (Not IsPrimaryCol(myCol, PKcols)) And (NormalizeDataTypeToDBtype(myCol) <> SqlDbType.Timestamp) Then
                ListFields = ListFields & Trim(myCol.ColumnName)
                ListFields = ListFields & ","
            End If
        Next
        ListFields = Mid$(ListFields, 1, Len(ListFields) - 1) & ")"

        'ottengo la lista dei parametri
        ListParam = " VALUES ("
        For Each myCol In ds.Tables(0).Columns
            If (Not IsPrimaryCol(myCol, PKcols)) And (NormalizeDataTypeToDBtype(myCol) <> SqlDbType.Timestamp) Then
                ListParam = ListParam & "@" & Trim(myCol.ColumnName)
                ListParam = ListParam & ","
                DBadapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@" & Trim(myCol.ColumnName), NormalizeDataTypeToDBtype(myCol)))
                DBadapter.InsertCommand.Parameters("@" & Trim(myCol.ColumnName)).SourceColumn = Trim(myCol.ColumnName)
            End If
        Next
        ListParam = Mid$(ListParam, 1, Len(ListParam) - 1) & ")"
        DBadapter.InsertCommand.CommandText = TmpSQLstring & ListFields & ListParam
        DBadapter.InsertCommand.Connection = CType(DBadapter.SelectCommand.Connection, SqlConnection)
        
 End Function
```

Comment: The *real* question is why are you injecting your value and not **parametrising** it.

Comment: parametrising where?

Comment: `VALUES (" + arrText.Item(indice) + ")` that's injection. You should use a parameter `VALUES (@txt)` and pass through the value separately

Comment: +1 On the parametrizations, but you actual problem is the data type mis-match.  TestTable.riga is not a string.  By surrounding the value you're inserting with "" you are implying it is.  Weather it is a string or not, the types have to match

Answer (score 1):

`Stream`s need to be disposed by calling `Dispose` or placing in a `Using` block. This is a text file so you don't even need a stream.

`ArrayList` is around for backward compatibility but you shouldn't be used in new code. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-5.0#remarks A good replacement is `List(Of T)`

I have broken the code into 3 methods. You are doing too many separate tasks in a single method. I have used `System.IO.File` class to read the file. `ReadAllLines` returns an array of the lines in the file. Then a simple For Each loop to identify the lines you want to add to the database. I used a `List(Of String)` to collect the lines. Then pass the list to the database code in `InsertText`.

Only the value of the parameter changes in the loop.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim FilePath = GetFilePath()
    If FilePath Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("No file selected.")
    End If
    Dim lst As New List(Of String)
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath)
    For Each line In lines
        If line.Contains("H06") AndAlso line.Contains("SPEKM")) Then
            lst.Add(line)
        End If
    Next
    InsertText(lst)
End Sub

Private Function GetFilePath() As String
    Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()
    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "Z:\FitalogItalia\KMaster\SPEKM"   'ATTENZIONE CAMBIARE IN "C:\"
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
    If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Return openFileDialog1.FileName
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function

Private Sub InsertText(lst As List(Of String))
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TestTable (riga) VALUES (@riga);", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@riga", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
        cn.Open()
        For Each line In lst
            cmd.Parameters("@riga").Value = line
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End Using 'closes the connection and disposes the command and the connection
End Sub
```